# How to disable Next button of Wizard Control at Step 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a wizard control and at very first time I want to disable Next button of it. I have another button at the same page and when user clicks on that button than it will enable the Next button. At very first it will be disable.

```
 <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" Runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0" DisplaySideBar="False">
                         <StartNavigationTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Next" />
                        </StartNavigationTemplate>
                        <FinishNavigationTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="FinishButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveComplete" Text="Finish" />
                        </FinishNavigationTemplate>
                            <WizardSteps>
                            <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" Runat="server" Title="IP Configuration">

                            </asp:WizardStep>
                            <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" Runat="server" Title="Register">

                            </asp:WizardStep>
                        </WizardSteps>
                        </asp:Wizard>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First You haven't converted your Wizard to Template. you would convert stepnavigation to template first, then use findcontrol to grab the button you want and change it programatically with .Enabled

```
 <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" Runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0" DisplaySideBar="False">
                     <StartNavigationTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Next" />
                    </StartNavigationTemplate>
                    <FinishNavigationTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="FinishButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveComplete" Text="Finish" />
                    </FinishNavigationTemplate>
                        <StepNavigationTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="StepPreviousButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="MovePrevious" Text="Previous" />
                            <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" 
                                Text="Next" />
                     </StepNavigationTemplate>
                        <WizardSteps>
                        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" Runat="server" Title="IP Configuration">

                        </asp:WizardStep>
                        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" Runat="server" Title="Register">

                        </asp:WizardStep>
                    </WizardSteps>
                    </asp:Wizard> 


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button nextButton = ((Button)Wizard1.FindControl("StartNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("StepNextButton"));
        nextButton.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways of achieving this task. but none seemed to work really. Like using template.findcontrol("... or using css to modify. None of them worked for me. So what I tried here is just dont let the user go onto next page unless they have met all the criteria the webpage requires. Suppose my textbox with password is empty.`if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPasskey.Text))`
And user clicks on next button. It will not move to next page unless unless the verification is done.

```
protected void NextButton_Click(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    cmdCancel.Visible = true;
    VerifyPassword();
    try
    {
        if (lblPasskeyInformation.Text[0] == 'I' || lblPasskeyInformation.Text[0] == 'P')
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblPasskeyInformation.Text = "You are not verified yet. Please enter the passkey.";
    }

}
```

You dont need try catch. You just need to place

```
 protected void NextButton_Click(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
 e.Cancel = true;
            return;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

No templates were used.

```
Button previousButton = Wizard1.WizardSteps[6]           // enter the correct index for WizardSteps
     .FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID")   // You get the button
     .FindControl("StepPreviousButton") as Button;       // This gives previous button.
```